# Was there a site participation right on SO for people with 5000 rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation

For some reason I seem to recall that SO FAQ's table of what can be done with N rep points included a data point for 5000 rep.

Yet, looking at the FAQ now, I no longer see it.

Was it just a fluke in my memory?

Or did the Matrix produce a black cat and changed the FAQ (and supposedly site rules) on me in the last month?

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It used to be that you could delete *any* comments from your post if you had 5000 rep. They changed that, though.

[Here](http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/128387-do-not-allow-users-to-delete-comments-on-their-questions-?ref=title) is the old UserVoice request detailing the reason:

Jeff's response was:

> comment flagging renders deletion obsolete

Basically, because you can flag any comments, there is no need for the feature any longer.

Comment: Thx! I KNOW I'm not completely nuts now :)