# Can we have a badge as a consolation prize for lack of 5000 rep powers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, badge-request

StackOverflow recently [removed the power to delete arbitrary comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25378/was-there-a-site-participation-right-on-so-for-people-with-5000-rep) from your post once you reach 5000 rep.

The change itself makes perfect sense, but it leaves those of us who strove to reach 5k rep feeling lost and without a milestone.

Therefore, I propose, as a consolation prize to keep the morale up for people pathetic enough to care (like myself) - a new badge for reaching 5k (may be remove it past 6k or something).

Proposed names:

- "T-Shirt" (I reached 5k rep and all I got was a lousy T-Shirt badge)
- ["James Madison"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_denominations_of_United_States_currency)

```
#include comments/<get-a-life.h>
#include comments/<get-better-priorities-in-life.h>
```

Comment: Your definition of "recently" is warped. Are you, perhaps, in the vicinity of a gravitational singularity?

Comment: Or travelling at relativistic speeds? Or maybe *I'm* travelling at relativistic speeds? Where are Patrick Stewart and Brent Spiner to explain science when you need them?

Comment: What if I'm trapped in a time loop? What if, to me, this change was made months and months ago, but to the rest of the world little to no time has passed at all!? What if I'm doomed to repeat the same few days over and over again? What if I never get out? Do I have enough time to fly to TXI's house and murder him before time repeats itself again? I think I might be able to bear eternity as long as I get to kill TXI whenever I want, knowing that he'll just come right back to life, healthy as a slug, every time. I should treat this as an opportunity!

Comment: **I knew it! Welbog is Bill Murray!**

Comment: @Welbog - I only recently noticed the change in the FAQ (like couple of weeks ago)

Comment: Actually, relativity has only a modest effect on the apparent speed of time compared to the age of the speaker and, more importantly, the age (and, sadly, number of activities) of the speaker's children.  For example, all of the activity occuring on SO seems recent to me whereas to those who graduated and got their first jobs last May the origin of SO is a programming eternity ago.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps Jeff Atwood will see this, have pity on you, and send you a few SO stickers to assuage your pain.

Comment: I am unaccepting this since Jeff never sent me any stickers :((((   Woe is me!

Answer (score 0):

You can still strive for 10K.

Comment: As per Joel, you should always break up a project into **small** tasks with milestones.